# Verify whether --require_secure_transport=ON for MySQL is working using Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, ssl

### I have to enable SSL for Spring Boot + MySQL App

I have enabled SSL for MySQL and set `--require_secure_transport=ON` in my.cnf.

---

When I try to log in to MySQL using

`mysql -unon_ssl_user -p -h XXX.XXX.100.158`

I get

`ERROR 3159 (HY000): Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.`

which is correct as secure transport is forced.

---

I am able to login to mysql using

`mysql -ussl_user -p -h XXX.XXX.100.158 --ssl-ca=ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem`

this also correct.

---

When I am using `non_ssl_user` or `ssl_user` **without certificates using spring boot**, I am able to connect to database.

My application.properties file contains:

```
-----
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.100.158:3306/ssl_db
spring.datasource.username=ssl_user
spring.datasource.password=*********
-----
```

I think mysql should not allow user/springboot app to connect to database without certificates.

---

Is this the intended behaviour?

Am I missing something here?

Thank you!